# Please take a look at my code with importXML

Tags: spreadsheet

I just want to get the price here : $35

Link : https://www.adidas.com/us/adilette-comfort-slides/AP9971.html

I'm using importxml :

```
=IMPORTXML(J13,"//div/span[@class='gl-price__value']")
```

But maybe it's wrong or missing at somewhere.

Please help me out of this !

Mntks & Brgds,

Comment: I checked this works in JS so should work in ImportXml too? `$x('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span')[0].textContent`

Comment: I have tried but it failed. :( i really want to solve it

Comment: Oh I see the website has changed now - maybe they pushed a new version. I think its better to reach the price container first and then filter down to the target element, like this: `$x('//div[contains(@class, "reviews_price_container_")]/div/span[contains(@class, "gl-price__value")]')`